# Removing the decimals from integers in facet graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
set.seed(123)
dat_freq_weight <- data.frame(
  feature = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  frequency = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.015, 0.0031, 0.0205),
  group = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group1", "Group2", "Group1")
)
p <- ggplot(data = dat_freq_weight, aes(x = reorder(dat_freq_weight$feature, -frequency), y = frequency)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightblue", color = "blue", width = 0.3) +
  facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Relative frequencies") 
print(p)
```

This is a reproducible example, **edited from the previous** that was too simple to be useful to me.

How can I remove the decimals that appear only in the integers of the second graph? I don't want "0.0" and so on, but only an integer number when its decimal would be 0.

**UPDATE**

```
scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = c(0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015, 0.02, 0.025),
    labels = c("0%", "0.5%", "1%", "1.5%", "2%", "2.5%"))
```

This is exactly what I needed for my facet graph. However, if there are more easier ways to do the same, I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are you aiming to make the second graph's y-axis go from 0 to 1 with no other breaks? Or do you want 0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1?

Comment: Just edited with a more clear reproducible example.

Comment: What do you want the labels to be in your new example?

Comment: @user2554330 I've just edited again. Labels don't seem necessary in the example.

Comment: So if you have breaks at 0 and 2.5%, you want to see labels of "0%" and "2.5%", is that the question?

Comment: @JonSpring the original facet graphs is made of 4 subplots. The first two have 0%, 1% and 2%. The last two subplots have 0.0%, 0.5%, 1.0%, 1.5% and 2.0%. I want to remove the ".0%" on the last two.

Comment: I think @stefan's answer does what you want.  If so, you should "accept" that answer; if not, you should leave a comment on it explaining what needs fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom function for the labels which first checks whether a break is an integer or not, then use an `ifelse` to conditionally set the format for the labels.

**EDIT** And thanks to the comment by @user2554330 there is actually a default `drop0trailing` option (see `?base::format`) which allows to achieve the desired result like so:

```
scale_x_continuous(
  labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = .1, drop0trailing = TRUE)
)
```

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(
  data = dat_freq_weight,
  aes(y = reorder(feature, -frequency), x = frequency)
) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = \(x) {
      # Is integer?
      ix <- !(abs((x * 100) %% 1) > 0)
      ifelse(
        ix,
        scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1)(x),
        scales::label_percent(accuracy = .1)(x)
      )
    }
  ) +
  geom_col(
    fill = "lightblue",
    color = "blue", width = 0.3
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free") +
  theme(
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Relative frequencies")
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice solution.  There's a simpler one, but I like yours better:  `scale::percent_format()` supports the obscure option `drop0trailing = TRUE` which achieves the same thing.  Takes some digging to find the docs for that, though.

Comment: @user2554330 Thx for pointing that out. Wasn't aware of that option. And in that case I would go for `drop0trailing = TRUE`. Feel free to add as an answer.

Comment: The advantage of your answer is that it will help anyone who wants to tweak the formatting of the labels in any way, not just dropping zeros.  That's why I like yours better.